Android users auto login Salesforce App everyday
Some of our Android users needed to verified their Salesforce app through verification code everyday, but most of the other org users didn't. Verified the app everyday was such annoying.
I checked the users' Login History, and found that they logged in during the restricted time. After being blocked by the restricted time, they were asked to activate their app at the next time login. When they did not bump into the restricted time, they would normally login without verifying.
However, the users confirmed they did not log in during the restricted time. It seemed that there is an automation every night, but the Salesforce support confirmed that there is no possibility for automation.
Login History
Regarding the “automatic” login every night, does anyone think there might be any possible reasons? Thank you!
-
Additional information:
This problem has occurred with phones of the following Types:

Samsung, Oppo, Sony, Vivo.

Login hours:

Allowed Login Hours: between 7:00 AM - 10:00 PM (Monday - Friday)

The session settings are as follows:

"Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated" is unchecked.
"Lock sessions to the domain in which they were first used" is checked.
"Force logout on session timeout" is checked.




Some Tests:

Salesforce Support suggested adding Login IP Range 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255 to the profile, which would allow users do not have to verify when they encounter a restricted time. After testing, we found indeed that Android users do not need to verify the app every day. However, we did not adopt this method due to security concerns.

We asked users to log out of Salesforce every day to see if it would prevent automatic login, but the result was still the same.


